# mac os x invoke calling another application from app

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I need to call another application inside my application (Mac OS X app). For example if I have  PDF in my bundle and I want to see it call load the PDF in the viewer app. How can call the viewer and load the PDF on bundle?, any of you knows how can I do this?, I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSWorkspace does this kind of stuff the documentation has near the top the example code

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"/Myfiles/README"
                        withApplication:@"TextEdit"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke, openURL to open the default PDF viewer

> [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile: pdfFilePath];

and if you want to launch the application you can invoke

> [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:appPath];

Want to open PDF within your application then I recommend you to read PDFKit:
[Apple PDFKit Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/PDFKitGuide/PDFKit_Prog_Intro/PDFKit_Prog_Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001863-CH203-SW1)