# Run another app from my app on OSX

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos

How can I run another app from my OSX app? For example, I want to run skype from my button in app.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: A similar question has been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone
Might be helpful!!!

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20875086/730701).

Comment: I tried to get solution for OSX. Why URL Scheme in iOS can be helpful for me?
NSWorkspace and NSTask can be used for this purpose. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NSTask](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/index.html).
But you will need to provide path for skype

See Swift [example](http://practicalswift.com/2014/06/25/how-to-execute-shell-commands-from-swift/):

```
let task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "/bin/skype"
task.arguments = ["first-argument", "second-argument"]
task.launch()
```